# HttpSendRequest trucate my value while HttpSendRequestA works as excepted

Tags: c++, http, post, http-headers, wininet

I want to send a POST value in C++ using `HttpSendRequest`. I test the requests on https://requestbin.net
I made this code :

```
void sendValue()
{
    LPCSTR header = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    std::string dataStr = u8"result=a very longue value !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)";
    LPVOID myMessage = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenA("InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnectA(hInternet, "requestbin.net", 80, " ", " ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnection, "POST", "/r/IDREQUESTBIN", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, header, strlen(header), myMessage, dataStr.size());
    std::cout << "wcslen(header) " << strlen(header) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dataStr.size() " << dataStr.size() << std::endl;
}
```

**It works perfectly**. I want to work with `wstring` now, I made this code :

```
void sendValueV2()
{
    LPCWSTR header = L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    std::wstring dataStr = L"result=a very longue value !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)";
    LPVOID myMessage = (LPVOID)dataStr.c_str();
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(L"InetURL/1.0", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnection = InternetConnect(hInternet, L"requestbin.net", 80, L" ", L" ", INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnection, L"POST", L"/r/IDREQUESTBIN", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 1);
    HttpSendRequest(hRequest, header, wcslen(header), myMessage, dataStr.size());
    std::wcout << "wcslen(header) " << wcslen(header) << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "dataStr.size() " << dataStr.size() << std::endl;
}
```

My POST value is truncated to : `result=a very longue value !!`

This is the output of my console :

```
wcslen(header) 62
dataStr.size() 58
wcslen(header) 62
dataStr.size() 58
```

Someone can explain me what happen ? I am going crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-httpsendrequestw), the `dwOptional` parameter to `HttpSendRequest` is expressed in bytes, not characters, so replace:

```
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, header, wcslen(header), myMessage, dataStr.size());
```

with:

```
HttpSendRequest(hRequest, header, wcslen(header), myMessage, dataStr.size() * sizeof (WCHAR));
```

and your problem should be resolved.